Ubuntu RDP set up for a windows user
I have a question around RDP access for a windows user:
The current set up, I have installed a form of RDP a while back on a virtual machine, which has Ubuntu, what happens though is every time the VM is rebooted it takes me to this screen. Where I have to enter in credentials before the end user can remotely access it:
enter image description here
Firstly I want to understand what this page is please and then how to remove it so I don't have to manually intervene, if a virtual machine is rebooted.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Does this screen appear when connecting via RDP? If yes, there's nothing unusual. Looks like it's just a login screen of your Ubuntu virtual machine. It works the same if you set up RDP access for a Windows machine: if the machine is rebooted and you try to access it via RDP - with NLA turned off - you are presented with a login screen and you have to login first, before you can access the desktop.
If the person using RDP access is someone else than you, that person probably also knows login & password in order to be able to access the machine; so he/she can login by him/herself, without need for you to login first.
